# View from space via google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Google Maps give opportunity to user to look on
[Earth from space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P33U3.jpg)
But Google Maps Javascript API 'Satellite' version allows to you zoom only to
[this version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et5hH.png)

How can I get view from Google Maps like at first screenshot? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about loading a web-gl rendered globe instead of imagery map tiles. This functionality has not been released to the javascript API. Google has started releasing some of their web gl functionality such as being able to toggle 3d mode in bigger cities but the "earth global view" web-gl functionality are lacking.